# Can't send values because they are coming as null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I populated three select components with values, the thing I want to do is when selecting from the medic input a value, the date and hour should change based on what is on the database, this is working as intended, the problem is, when I'm dispatching, the medic value is arriving in the database, but the hour and date are coming as null. Here is the logic:

```
const specialty = useSelector((state) => state.specialty);
      const { specialtyInfo} = specialty;
      let doctorArray = [];
      let hourArray = [];
      let dateArray = []


      specialtyInfo?.medicalspecialty.forEach(function (el) {
        doctorArray.push(el.last_name)
      });


      useEffect(() => {
        specialtyInfo?.medicalspecialty.forEach(function (el) {
            if(el.last_name == medic) {
                dispatch(getData(el.id))
            }
          });
      }, [medic]);

      const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);
      const { dataInfo } = data;

      dataInfo?.data.forEach(function (el) {
        hourArray.push(el.hour);
      });

      dataInfo?.data.forEach(function (el) {
        dateArray.push(el.date);
      });
```

Everything here is done with redux and react, on the user interface I have the following:

```
<div>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 step4 />
      <form className="form" >
       <div>
          <label htmlFor="medic">Medic</label>
          <select name="medic" onChange={(e) => setMedic(e.target.value)}>
            {doctorArray.map((medic) => {
              return (
                <option value={medic} key={medic}>
                  {medic}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
          <select name="date" onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}>
            {dateArray.map((date) => {
              return (
                <option value={date} key={date}>
                  {date}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>

         <div>
          <label htmlFor="hour">Hour</label>
          <select name="hour" onChange={(e) => setHour(e.target.value)}>
            {hourArray.map((date) => {
              return (
                <option value={date} key={date}>
                  {date}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div className="bookButton">
               <button className="buttonAccount " type="submit" onClick={(e)=>{submitHandler(e);}}>
                    Confirm Booking
              </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, nothing special just three components with exactly the same logic. Here is the dispatcher, that is sending data into the database and is triggered when clicking a button:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(sendEmail(
            medic, 
            date, 
            hour, 
            userInfoInfo.userEmail,
            userInfoInfo.fullName,
            userInfoInfo.height,
            userInfoInfo.sex,
            userInfoInfo.weight,
            userInfoInfo.age,
            userInfoInfo.city,
            filtered_list[0].name,
            filtered_list[0].possibility))
      };
```

I'm 100% percent, I'm doing something really wrong in here, because the select boxes are with null values.

Comment: Do you have the code running in the react sandbox?

Comment: Sadly, I have way too many components and files, that's why I just wrote in here just the important pieces, that aren't working properly. I think the problem is because I'm not setting the setDate and setHour properly.

Comment: There is no code for `setDate` etc., what are they?